# C++: Text fields with custom structures to support math or any other form

Tags: c++, qt, math, symbols, symbolic-math

I would like to design an interface that would contain notebook formulation of math symbols. So I want to be able to write something like a big square root which extends automatically with what I have under it, or a fraction which is dynamical to extend, also, as much as I enter data in the numerator or denominator.

So basically something similar to what we see in Maple, Mathematica or MathCAD.

How do we start in such designs? What are the tools for the job?

I'm right now just worried about how to display this stuff on a custom interface. I'm planning on doing this with Qt as the library for the interface. I'm pretty an expert in C++ and experienced in Qt.

Thank you for any efforts.

[image]

Comment: A formula-editor such as MathType typically does all drawing itself. It treats every typable field as a rectangle, and large operators are drawn "outside" the rectangles and scaled to fit. The rectangles themselves act as "input fields" for typable text; the large operators need a sort of interface.

Comment: @Jongware So you're telling me I have to rebuild the interface from nothing? This is too much! How do I start with that? Any idea?

Comment: The previous comment outlines my general idea -- I thought about it for another platform, not QT. It seems not difficult, only lots of work, what with all strings measurements and such. But apparently there *are* QT-ready solutions: [google turned up this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5247609/math-renderer-widget-in-qt).

Comment: @Jongware this gives a rendering solution not a text editing solution... I mean I can with MathML enter codes and expect Qt to draw them as math, but I can't "write" math in a field directly like those programs (mathematica, maple, ...) do. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Qt documentation, you can display Unicode symbols in a QLabel including mathematical symbols:
http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6936

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_alphanumeric_symbols_Unicode_block
http://qtway.blogspot.com/2010/04/mathml-editor-using-qt-support-for.html

Comment: But adding Unicode doesn't make the stuff look like the picture I added. Perhaps MathML is a way to do it, I'm not sure though.

Comment: MathML is a storage format and has nothing to do with *display* -- unless you integrate a complete MathML renderer.